# How to remove properties from multiple objects if its not undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

trying to delete properties from object its throwing error if it does not have value what is correct way to delete similar properties from multiple objects.

main.js

```
  if (data.details.primary.transactionHistory !== undefined ||
                        data.details.secondary.transactionHistory !== undefined) {
                        delete data.details.primary.transactionHistory;
                        delete data.details.secondary.transactionHistory;
                    }
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Check each property exists before deleting

Comment: can not read object null or undefined

Comment: is there better way to check that instead of putting if condition for each property

Comment: after setting data i want to delete only that is part of `details` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **AND** condition instead of **OR**. In your logic, `delete` operation will get fired if either case is true. Just replace `||` with `&&`

```
if (data.details.primary.transactionHistory !== undefined &&
                        data.details.secondary.transactionHistory !== undefined) {
                        delete data.details.primary.transactionHistory;
                        delete data.details.secondary.transactionHistory;
                    }
```

Edit 1:

If you have nested object, it is better to check properties step-by-step.

```
if (data.details && data.details.primary && data.details.primary.transactionHistory !== undefined) {
  delete data.details.primary.transactionHistory
}
```

Now event if `primary` is not a property of `details`, your code will not fail.

You can simplify accordingly.

Comment: this condition only satisfy if properties are in both object thats not going to be the case some ids does not return secondary , i only want to delete properties that are part of `details` object

Comment: if i have data that returns only `data.details.primary.transactionHistory ` this condition will fail

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're checking whether `transactionHistory` is not `undefined`

Try this:

```
const details = data.details;

if (details) {

  if(details.primary) {
    details.primary.transactionHistory = null;
    // or
    delete details.primary.transactionHistory;
  }

  if(details.secondary) {
    details.secondary.transactionHistory = null;
    // or
    delete details.secondary.transactionHistory;
  }

}
```

This will **essentially** do the same thing that you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: why dont we just delete using your approach setting to null is good practice ?

Comment: This actually doesn't do the same thing. This allows the memory held by the object to be gc'd (assuming it has 0 ref counts), but it will not delete the property entry in the host object.

Comment: @Rafael, I think I've played with words here. :P Yeah it will still keep the key on the object but eventually it would be freed.

Answer (score 0):

If your want to delete `transactionHistory` in general and you don't want to create `if-statements` for each nested object within `data.details`, you can do:

```js
// Data for snippet
let data = {
  details: { 
    primary: { transactionHistory: 'blah' }, 
    secondary: { transactionHistory: 'blah', someOtherProp: 'still here' },
    nohistory: {},
    miscproperties: { shouldNotBeDeleted: true }
  }
}

// Deletion of transactionHistory from data
Object.keys(data.details).map((item) => { delete data.details[item].transactionHistory })

console.log(data)
```

You can add whatever conditionals you need within the open and closing brackets if necessary.

Comment: what would happen if object does not have those properties we are trying to delete in this case if we dont have if statements

Comment: If `transactionHistory` is the only thing you need to delete and it doesn't have that property, it will not error. Updated the snippet. Of course, you are free to add whatever you need to be deleted inside the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this frequently, you should generalize it:

```js
function clean_up(objects, keys) {
    objects.forEach(o => {
        keys.forEach(k => {
            try {
                let base = k.split('.');
                let del = base.pop();
                let host = base.reduce((o, k) => o[k], o);
                delete host[del];
            } catch (e) {}
        });
    });
    return objects;
}

console.log(
    clean_up([{a: {b: 5}}, {z: 3, b: {} }, {c: 8}], ['a.b', 'c'])
);
```